# How to space nested and unnested objects evenly using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am not quite sure how to phrase this question, but I am having some problems with even spacing using flexbox. I am building a header in WordPress and I want even spacing between all menu elements. The problem is that I have two other elements that are not part of the automatically generated menu in WordPress. I also need them to be evenly spaced at the same distance as the nested list elements of the menu.

I feel that my knowledge is lacking here and I need some pointers on how to approach this. In basic terms, here is my code:

```css
.logo {
  width: 15%;
  float: left;
}

.nav-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
  flex: 2;
}

.nav-container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 2;
}

.nav-container ul {
  display: flex;
  flex: 2;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div class="logo">
    Logo
  </div>

  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <nav class="nav-container">
      <ul>
        <li>Menu Item</li>
        <li>Menu Item</li>
        <li>Menu Item</li>
        <li>Menu Item</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="search">
      <span class="search-text">Search</span>
    </div>

    <div class="mega-menu-button">
      <button>
       Menu
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3qo56h8j/1/

Now, this is a mess. Probably not correct at all. The problem is that I do not see where the mistakes are and could use some help. The vertical alignment is off, but I can fix that. The big problem is how to space the search and mega menu button at the same distance as the menu items that are generated by WordPress? Preferably in a way that scales with the screen.

And I can't just move the other items into the list because the list is generated by WordPress.

Comment: You can't use flex properties for this since flexbox only affects direct child elements. So while you can space the list items you can't space them in relation to the parent's siblings

Answer (score 0):

You are doing well just need to calculate flex for each container.

```
header {
    display: flex;
}

.logo {
    flex: 1;
}

.nav-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    float: right;
    flex: 6;
}

.nav-container {
    display: flex;
    flex: 4;
}

.nav-container ul {
    display: flex;
    flex: 2;
    justify-content: space-between;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-container li {
    flex: 1;
}

.search {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using flex properties from top to bottom. Start with the header. Then space items accordingly.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
}

.logo,
.nav-wrapper,
.search,
.mega-menu-button {
  flex: 1 0 10%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav-wrapper {
  flex-basis: 70%;
}

.nav-container {
  flex: 1;
}

.nav-container ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div class="logo">Logo</div>

  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <nav class="nav-container">
      <ul>
        <li>Menu Item</li>
        <li>Menu Item</li>
        <li>Menu Item</li>
        <li>Menu Item</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div><!-- new; close .nav-wrapper -->

  <div class="search">
    <span class="search-text">Search</span>
  </div>

  <div class="mega-menu-button">
    <button>
       Menu
      </button>
  </div>

</header>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b0594cxo/)